# Помогите с регулярным выражением (учебный пример, американские часы)

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Нужно написать паттерн регулярного выражения, чтобы результат был True только для вариантов, когда значения чаcов соответствуют американскому стилю, т.е., часы от 1 до 12, минуты от 00 до 59. Внимание, основная проблема: строка с нулем впереди (например, 05:45am - не "засчитывается", "засчитывается" только 5:45am.

```
pattern = '^[[1?[1-9]]|10]\:[0-5]\d\s?[APap]|[Mm]$'
result = re.search(pattern, text)
```

Такой мой код не работает корректно
Спасибо

Comment: [Один из вариантов](https://regex101.com/r/4tr2CC/1)

Comment: Спасибо. Незнакомый мне синтаксис, ?: . Поизучаю.

Comment: re.search(r'^([1-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9][ap]m$', ln, re.I | re.MULTILINE)